ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER while running a Nex.js app

⨯ TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12502:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async postJSON (file:///D:/earn/node_modules/.pnpm/@planetscale+database@1.19.0/node_modules/@planetscale/database/dist/index.js:125:22)
    at async Connection.execute (file:///D:/earn/node_modules/.pnpm/@planetscale+database@1.19.0/node_modules/@planetscale/database/dist/index.js:81:23)
    at async PrismaPlanetScale.performIO (file:///D:/earn/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+adapter-planetscale@5.22.0_@planetscale+database@1.19.0/node_modules/@prisma/adapter-planetscale/dist/index.mjs:151:22)
    at async PrismaPlanetScale.queryRaw (file:///D:/earn/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+adapter-planetscale@5.22.0_@planetscale+database@1.19.0/node_modules/@prisma/adapter-planetscale/dist/index.mjs:122:22)
    at async D:\earn\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.22.0_prisma@5.22.0\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:29:14083 {
  clientVersion: '5.22.0',
  page: '/',
  [cause]: [Error: 141C0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:
  ] {
    library: 'SSL routines',
    reason: 'wrong version number',
    code: 'ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER'
  }
}

Getting this error when trying to visit localhost on a Next.js app.
The above error comes when visiting the http://localhost:3000
Feeling a bit lost here, not sure what exactly the issue could be, this is the app which I'm trying to run: https://github.com/SuperteamDAO/earn
Just a guess but maybe it seems to be related to the src/prisma.ts file (You can check on GitHub), since the planet scale which error mentions only seems to be used in that fine.
To reproduce the error, simply try running the app in https://github.com/SuperteamDAO/earn this repository and it shows that error when you try opening the app on localhost.
In any case, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Tried running the app with flag --experimental-https
Tried from different devices
Tried with both a locally hosted MySQL database and one hosted online on a service in case it's related


"... visiting the http://localhost:3000" - this is a HTTP-URL, not HTTPS. But this kind of error can only happen with HTTPS. So either the URL you gave is wrong or there is somewhere a redirect to HTTPS. The error itself has commonly nothing to do with wong SSL version but instead happens when trying to access a site with HTTPS even though there is only plain HTTP configured on the given port. So my guess is that you either have not properly configured HTTPS in the app or that you used the wrong URL.
